# Save a cell area in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook that allows me to calculate values in a sheet called "Calc_tool". Now I need to use it for several soils and I would like to have a button at the end of my table that:

1. creates a new sheet (in the same workbook)
2. copy the data from my first sheet and paste in the new sheet (keeping the column width)
3. clear the initial table so that I can enter the data of the next soil

[Edit] Thanks to the community, here is the code that does it:

```
Sub Clearcells()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add _
    (After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calc_tool").Range("B3:I59").Copy
    With Range("B2")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calc_tool").Range("D3:D54").ClearContents
    Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calc_tool").Activate
End Sub
```

Hope this will help others!

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, there is a way to do steps 1 and 2. • But did you do some research before asking? You should be able to find **a lot** of tutorials how to add a worksheet to a workbook and how to copy data from one worksheet into another. Give it at least a try, and if you get stuck or errors come back with the code you tried and ask a question to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code does what you want:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim sheet As Worksheet
   Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add _
   (After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A5:A12").Copy 
   Destination:=sheet.Range("E5")
   Dim colWidth As Long
   colWidth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A5:A12").ColumnWidth
   sheet.Range("E5").ColumnWidth = colWidth
End Sub
```

Sheet1 is where the range you want to copy is. E5 is the range where you want to paste your cells in the created worksheet.
Hope that helps!

Comment: I just would recommend to relplace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook`. `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus and this can easily change by a single user click or whatever. But `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the code is written in (and this will never change) and therefore is more reliable to use (unless you write an add-in).

Comment: Thank you so much @RustyBucketBay and @PEH! I combined your answers with a last command I found on another post to come back to my original sheet and it looks like this now: 
````Sub Clearcells()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add _
    (After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("outil_calcul_STIR").Range("B2:G33").Copy _
    Destination:=sheet.Range("B2")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("outil_calcul_STIR").Range("D5:D31,E5:E31").ClearContents
    Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("outil_calcul_STIR").Activate
End Sub
````

Comment: How can I keep the column width in this code? When I add ````PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths```` after ````Destination:=sheet.Range("B2") ```` it does not work

Comment: updated in the answer, following my exmple logic + the Peh tip (thisWorkboook)

Comment: even better and shorter than what I had found elsewhere for column width! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Command to create a new sheet is

```
Sheets.Add
```

There are thousands of commands to copy content, one is

```
Range(TargetRange).value = Range(InputRange).value
```

If the ranges are at different sheets, add sheets("sheetname"). in front of each range or set variables as worksheets.

One command for your last requirement is in your question already.
Total code could look like this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet
   Dim sh2 As Worksheet
   Dim oRange As String
   Dim tRange As String

   Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1") '<- replace Sheet 1 with your input sheet's name
   oRange = "D5:E31" '<- Input Range in sheet 1
   tRange = "D5:E31" '<- Target Range in sheet 2

   Sheets.Add
   Set sh2 = ActiveSheet

   sh2.Range(tRange).Value = sh1.Range(oRange).Value
   sh1.Range(oRange).ClearContents
End Sub
```